# My admin panel view fancy box not working

Tags: views

I am new to drupal. I searched this problem in google but could not get the solution that could solve my problem. My problem is,

I used a fancybox for one of my news post page. It uses latest version of Jquery. When, I use this, my fancybox works well. But, when I come to view page, My light box does not work there. Like,

When I click on add button [Add button to add fileds or filters ], the sceen goes black and nothing happens. When I remove the fancybox, it works well. It is important for me to use fancybox. Please suggest how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same problem. This is due to jquery problem. Let me tell you that jquery contains default support to jquery. It uses older version of jquery in its core. So, if u want to use that module, then, what u can do is:

1. Download [jquery update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module and enable the moudle,
2. Then you open the project code, moudles folder and find the jquery update moulde, there you will find replace folder. You, will find various version of jquery there. You can include or replace the latest version of jquery.
3. However the drupal core works in older version, so what you can do is open the jquery_update.module file and find the line that says.

   // Replace files for jQuery 1.7 and up
         if (version_compare($version, '1.7', '>=')) {
           $javascript['drupal.states']['js']['misc/states.js']['data'] = $path . '/replace/misc/1.7/states.js';
     }
   Now what you need to do is. You need to check, if the user is logged in then replace the jquery with core old jquery and if user is not logged in then, use the latest your fancybox jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same thing and patched fancy box. There was a missing permission for the settings page.

You might like to grab the dev release. http://drupal.org/node/1888814