# How to use latest jquery version on specific page or code?

Tags: 7

i am using D7. i want to use jquery1.9 on a specific block. so at where that block visible, only load jquery with it. how it wil??? any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I make a custom theme I use a little different solution. Maybe it's not perfect (and is very redundant) but I can use latest jQuery with my theme. I'm creating jquery.js with following code:

```
var oldjQuery = jQuery;
// latest jQuery code goes here 
var jQuery19 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
jQuery = $ = oldjQuery;
```

and main.js with my whole JavaScript surrounded with:

```
(function($) {
  // my JavaScript code
})(jQuery19);
```

This allows me to use latest jQuery in my themes and default Drupal jQuery with admin theme. I'm adding this files directly in tpl.php files or sometimes in .info file. I'm sure you can use this also with custom blocks.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it. If you want to update  jquery, you can use [jquery update moudle.](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update)

Second thing is you can use, `drupal_add_js()` function to include the jquery file to particular node.

Third thing is you can use the js, that is used in all the page in template.php or in theme.info file. I hope you are looking for second method. Also, this question will help you much.

[Updating jquery](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63202/my-admin-panel-view-fancy-box-not-working)